# Sniffing 802.11 and 3G network

Tags: 3g, sniffing, 3g-network, wifi

I'm doing some experiments over 802.11 and 3G/GSM networks. So that, my machine has to "sniff" traffic both wlan and 3G network. On the Wlan i think i can manage that by using wireshark. But, 3G network i can't find any sniffer for that.. also.. I don't have any 3G adaptor. Can anyone give me some advice on this?

Kind regards.

Comment: [Here's how to code a program that sniffs Wi-Fi.](http://www.wireshark.org/download/automated/src/)

Comment: Try this question over at http://security.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com

Comment: Give a look at this link, it may help you: http://serverfault.com/questions/311873/can-3g-networks-be-packet-sniffed-analyzed

Comment: For wifi i know, and i use wireshark of course. But i've been wondering if there were some adaptar (and of course some software) to sniff 3G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a 3G modem, look at this [one](http://www.ebay.in/itm/Huawei-E1732-3G-usb-modem-Data-Card-7-2Mbps-Unlocked-Idea-Net-Setter-Bill-/280770863669?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item415f3f6235#ht_4514wt_976).
But, the problem in Sniffing 3G is that the data communicated with the base station is ciphered, you may try, but i don't think that Wireshark per example can sniff 3G data!

Answer (score 1):

You can't sniff anything without a proper hardware. Get a 3G adaptor.

Comment: Yes, but, if you may, where can i find one? i find nothing on ebay :-/